# Nodejs Express - res.send(<a very long string>) freeze when sending result back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JS and Node. I just started learning it yesterday so I am probably not doing things the right way.

I have a NodeJS application and I stood up a server using express. The client will make a get request to this server and the server will do some API call/calculation then when the result is ready the server will send the result back to client. This is what I have now

app.mjs

```
app.get('/log', function (req, res) {
  ...
  function callback(data) {
    res.send(data);
  }
  deviceHandler.getLog(filteredDevices, callback);
}
)
```

and the deviceHander.mjs

```
class DeviceHandler {
  ...
  getLog(device, callback) {
    var handler = this.deviceHandlers[device.type]
    handler.getLog(device, callback)
  }
}
```

one of the devices is iPhone so here is a snippet of iphoneDeviceHandler.mjs

```
IphoneDeviceHandler.prototype.getLog = function(device, callback) {
  get(url, callback);
};
```

finally here is my get function

```
function get(url, callback, method='GET') {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open(method, url, true);
  ...
  http.onload = function() {
    if (http.status != 200) {
      callback(`Error ${http.status}: ${http.statusText}`);
    } else { // show the result
      // callback(http.responseText) <--- this freeze
      console.log(Buffer.byteLength(http.responseText, "utf-8")); <-----1323196 bytes so 1.3 MB but sometimes it can be up to 5MB
    }
  };
  http.send();
}
```

---

This works but I think I am doing something wrong because my terminal keeps freezing everything after I make one call. Here are the questions

1. The terminal freeze after I make one requets to my localhost server. Unsure why but I suspect it has to do with my callback function? It started after I added the callback.
2. The getting log operation takes a while, this is why I use synchronize call `http.open(method, url, false);` . Is that ok? I heard sync is generally frown upon in JS world? (again I am super new to it) or should I do async but then how can I give the response back to the client before res.send() is called in app.mjs?
3. What is the recommended way to stream back progress?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet above, I saw a place where you are using the callback inside a foreach loop. From my experience, what I can understand is you should call the callback when the whole process is over,

And also, you are using res.send() inside a callback, and which call back is part of a loop. (If you pass one device, then its ok, but for multiple devices it will run res.send() multiple times)
And if you run res.send() once, then the client-side won't receive future res.send() as the connection will get closed from both end.

Comment: Welcome to SO! and thanks! That makes sense. I updated the code to do send once outside of for loop, but it still froze after I make one request to the server at localhost. I updated the code above to reflect what I have now

Comment: the freezing issue might be related to some other thing.

Answer (score -1):

You should to set response status and if you need you can also set the cookies and headers

res.status(200).json({ data })

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! Can you give some precis example/explanation?

Comment: const jwtToken = jwt.sign({
        sub: user._id,
        id: user._id,
        role: user.role,
      }, config.SECRET, { expiresIn: 30 }) //30 second

      res.cookie('jwt-token', jwtToken, {
        maxAge: COOKIE_EXPIRES,
        httpOnly: false,
        sameSite: true,
        secure: false
      })

      res.status(201).json({
        user: {
          login: user.login,
          _id: user._id,
          role: user.role
        },
        refresh: refToken.token
      })

Comment: above, I gave an example of the code where an authorization token is created and set in the response cookie

Comment: and off course you should to call response out of loop